# How to add data to the grid from another selected record of another grid

Tags: grid, extjs

I am using RowEditor plugin for my grid. Grid record has three buttons: choose,update,cancel. When I click on choose it will display another grid and user has to click on one record, then some values of that record have to display on the previous grid. How to do this ?
I am using extjs 3.0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on choose - show a modal window popup with grid. When you open that popup pass a callback into constructor of the popup. Then force user to select only one record in grid (using rowselectmodel). On itemclick even of the child grid - call your callback and pass selected data in the parent grid. Update parent's grid record with this data.

Hope I was clear.

Comment: Thank you, i just did evrything what you have written but i need to show the data (some records of the child into parent) and the row is in still editable mode with three buttons
and when i click update the data from child grid will go into DB. User may edit or may not edit remaining fields. I completed everything what u have written but i am not getting how to show that data from child grid to the parent grid current row (which is in editable mode)

Comment: you could always get currently edited row. Using parent grid selection model and then you can update record at this row. You can also update editors in currently open RowEditor. It might be a be a bit complex to handle all this moments, but it's doable :).

Comment: Can you send me some sample code please? I don't know how to code this. my email is: thorusan@gmail.com thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To figure out which row the user selected, use the Ext.grid.GridPanel's SelectionModel. The default model is Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel (use `selModel` config setting to change the default). To grab the selected row, call `myGridPanel.getSelectionModel().getSelected()`. That will return an Ext.data.Record. Dig into that data to populate the original grid/store.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I have done the required things.
How I have done is, just passed the editor to my function and using selection model, I got the values and have placed them into the editor.

```
val1 = selectedArray[0].get('val1');
var cm = grid.colModel, fields = editor.items.items, f, val;
f = fields[1];
f.setValue(val1);
editor.values[f.id] = val;
```

This makes my life easier.

But, I have another problem, after placing into the editor. I have to do validation in the `afteredit` event, if user clicks the update button. In the `afteredit` event,

```
afteredit: function(object, changes, record, rowIndex)
{
    // I have to do validation on the changes; but its an object. How will I do it 
    ???
}
```